# How to make Clojure command line

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am new to Clojure, I wish to create a command line in clojure.

I am using lein, The app is simply waiting for user to type something and when press enter, it will print the line.

I cannot seems to make Clojure wait forever with `lein run`
Is there any other way?

Here is my code.

```
(defn -main [& args] 
   (read-line)
)
```

so when I type something and press enter, the whole code stops,
I want to take the input of user typing and process it continuously.
I mean each time user press enter, he/she should be able to continue to next line and program will run forever.

Comment: You should post your attempt. Without seeing anything I would guess you are using something like `map` on a lazy sequence that is not getting realized. When using from the repl it does get realized because the repl attempts to print the result.

Comment: hi @Shlomi , will update the code, but really. I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop for the user inputs then and provide some means to break the loop (yet, ctrl-c also works).  E.g.

```
(loop []
  (let [input (read-line)]
    (if (= input "quit")
      (println "bye")
      (do
        (println "You said: " input)
        (recur)))))
```